# Dropzone.js - uploading only 1 file multiple times on multiple file upload

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, dropzone.js, multiple-file-upload

I'm using Dropzone.js to submit a bunch of files with other form elements, as highlighted on https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone, however, on dragging multiple different files in the dropzone and submitting the form, it turns out that only one of them is uploaded. I'm also keeping track of files uploaded in my database, and it seems that depending of the number of files dragged into the dropzone for upload, a single file was being uploaded that many number of times. E.g: I drag 5 diff images with diff filenames into the dropzone, one of them being 'sunshine.jpg', it turns out 'sunshine.jpg' was recorded in the database 5 times. On further probing, I found out via the Network Panel in the Chrome dev tools, only one file was being sent multiple times in an array in the request header. Been troubleshooting for a while, to not much avail. Any insights would be appreciated.

Condensed HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate class="dropzone" id="mydropzone" name="create-form">
<div class="input-group" id="whatever">
   <div id="dropzonePreview">
        <div class="fallback">
            <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
...Other form elements
<input style="margin-bottom:15px;" id="btn_main_2" type="button" name="create" value='<?php echo $create_button; ?>' class="btn btn-large btn-success">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
Dropzone.options.mydropzone = { 
          url: 'Modules/global/module-fileuploads-dropzone.2.php', 
          addRemoveLinks: true,
          autoProcessQueue: false, 
          autoDiscover: false,
          paramName: 'file', 
          previewsContainer: '#dropzonePreview', 
          clickable: false, 
          uploadMultiple: true,
          parallelUploads: 100,
          maxFiles: 100,
          accept: function(file, done) {
            console.log("uploaded file");
            done();
          },
         error: function(file, msg){
            alert(msg);
          },
          init: function() {

              var myDropzone = this;

            $("#btn_main_2").on('click',function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               myDropzone.processQueue(); 

            });

          } 

        };
```

Screenshot of Network Log:

[image: Network Log - Request Header]

Comment: can you show your controller side code?

Comment: I thought I already provided that above. Do you mean the server side code that receives the files payload and processes them for uploading? I think that would be irrelevant here, since the problem is arising somewhere in client side itself, with the same file being attached multiple times in an array in the response header as noted by the Chrome Dev tools' Network Log.

Comment: `myDropzone.on("addedfile", function (file) {
              console.log(file);
                });`  check this is file is uploading properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further troubleshooting, I found the solution to this problem is considerably simple:

```
paramName: 'file[]'
```

instead of

```
paramName: 'file'
```

since we are dealing with an array of files in this case. Looks like one cannot ignore that while specifying an array as parameter.

Comment: Where do you put this?

Comment: Yeah where does this go?  I put it in options and nothing changes.  Still get this same behaviour.  Ive been on this for 2 days now.  I dont want to have to force my users to upload only one file at a time.  Ugh

Answer (score 0):

Using attribute uploadMultiple.

```
uploadMultiple:true
```

Whether to send multiple files in one request. If this it set to true, then the fallback file input element will have the multiple attribute as well. This option will also trigger additional events (like processingmultiple)